# importing multiple xml files

Tags: mysql, xml, cron

I'm after a bit of advice here if possible.

I basically have 12 XML files which I need to use in my mysql db. These xml files are all in a completely different structure and the data changes constantly.

With this in mind what would be the best approach for bringing this in and using it and updating it. I had thought to use a cronjob to execute a php file to write each of these into thier own table, but baring in mind there are 12 files, with around 60 lines in each file and the cron job will need to run every 15 minutes I think this will end up killing the server.

Any ideas on a solution would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LOAD_XML command in mysql to do this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

If the data is changed constantly in the XML files, how often does it need to be up to date in the database?  If the database is just a backing record for the XML, then maybe you can update once or twice an hour.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply to this. Basically I will be using this XML all over my site to feed different elements, and because this data changes alot ideally I need to update it atleast twice an hour. The main thing is that the xml data ties in with some of my own data and I need to be able to filter on all of this data, hence trying to bring it in to the db. Do you think load_xml will handle this ok?